# Changing Order of Wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My menu works fine as it is, but its currently using the ASC order.  I tried changing it to DESC with the code below:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 9, 'order' => 'DESC' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

any reason why the 'order' argument doesnt work?

Comment: DESC is the default usage in wordpress

Comment: @Trey I just tried ASC with the same result.. the menu doesn't change

Comment: hmmm according to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) that is the default... if all else fails you could just `array_reverse` the result

Comment: @Trey I got it working thanks! would select your answer but its under my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) that is the default... if all else fails you could just `array_reverse` the result

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually telling it what to order by. Only that it needs to be descending.

so try something like:

```
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => 9, 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'DESC' );
```